# Get Current DateTime in PHP for Spacific Timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime

The problem is really simple, but don't know why things are not working in a simple way.

I want to have datetime of specific timezones. My server's timezone is `America/Chicago` but I want to get current datetime of different timezones.

1. I don't want to `date_default_timezone_set` as it changes timezone for all datetime functions.
2. I tried `$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Stockholm'));` with different timezone values but all returns the same value.

Consider the following code

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "The current server time is: " . $current_time . "\r\n";

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo "America/New_York = ". $now->getTimestamp() . "\r\n";  

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Stockholm'));
echo "Europe/Stockholm = ". $now->getTimestamp() . "\r\n";  

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Muscat'));
echo "Asia/Muscat = ".$now->getTimestamp() . "\r\n"; 

$current_time  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "The current server time is: " . $current_time   . "\r\n";
```

The above code results in following output

```
The current server time is: 2015-04-04 17:06:01
America/New_York = 1428185161
Europe/Stockholm = 1428185161
Asia/Muscat = 1428185161
The current server time is: 2015-04-04 17:06:01
```

And all three values are same, means `new DateTimeZone(XYZ)` didn't work. The expected/required output should echo current time of those specific timezones.

Please advice if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix Timestamps are always in UTC and therefore always the same. Try using the `c` formatter to see the differences:

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "The current server time is: " . $current_time . "\r\n";

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo "America/New_York = ". $now->format('c') . "\r\n";  

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Stockholm'));
echo "Europe/Stockholm = ". $now->format('c') . "\r\n";  

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Muscat'));
echo "Asia/Muscat = ".$now->format('c') . "\r\n"; 

$current_time  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "The current server time is: " . $current_time   . "\r\n";

The current server time is: 2015-04-04 22:26:56
America/New_York = 2015-04-04T18:26:56-04:00
Europe/Stockholm = 2015-04-05T00:26:56+02:00
Asia/Muscat = 2015-04-05T02:26:56+04:00
The current server time is: 2015-04-04 22:26:56
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/308602)

Comment: so only difference was use of `$now->format( )` instead of `$now->getTimestamp( )`. I tried with `Y-m-d H:i:s` format instead of `c` and everything looks good now. Marking the answer accepted. Thanks dear.